# How do I find all my Smart Groups, as a type?

Tags: groups, smartgroups

I can search by Group name under Contacts -> Manage Groups -> Find but that does not find Smart Groups unless 'smart' is part of the name I created for the Group. How can I find all Groups of type Smart Groups?

Answer (score 3):

Curious as to what your use case for this is.

This is currently not part of group search. I suspect its an easy modification to add a checkbox to group search to include (or exclude) smart groups (along with any other criteria mentioned)

The DB query changes to enable this is relatively easy (column saved_search_id is NULL / NOT NULL)

lobo

Comment: Thanks Lobo. The use case is having dozens, hundreds of groups we have created but only a subset are Smart Groups and wanting a quick way  to pull up that subset of Smart Groups. I'l take a stab at the modification.

Answer (score 2):

It's not part of group search currently. As Lobo said, adding it would be a fairly quick task if you are a developer or wish to hire one.

One workaround would be to use the api explorer (in the menu, **Help > Developer > API Explorer**).

### Input like this:

[image]

### Will give output like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Coleman, I'm making an attempt at adding the checkbox.